# GroPro Live Preview on Android

Tags: javascript, php, live-streaming, gopro

I am working on a project and I need to show a live preview from GoPro Hero4 on web. Does anyone know how to do this?

I know that GoPro feeds work in their own network with the address:

> http://10.5.5.9:8080/gp/gpControl/

But I cannot find how to show what I am looking at on the camera.

There is an application on Google Play that allows to watch a live preview in Android, but I cannot use it because I have to make my own application.

I hope someone can help me - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Answer for those stumbling on this post.

First, HTTP Get this URL: `http://10.5.5.9/gp/gpControl/execute?p1=gpStream&a1=proto_v2&c1=restart` and then you can get a UDP stream by using this URL:

`udp://10.5.5.9:8554` (you might have a hard time using this in your work...)

**NOTE**: If using ffplay (ffMPEG), try using the `nobuffer` flag, for a low latency stream. More info can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/gopro/comments/2md8hm/how_to_livestream_from_a_gopro_hero4/cr1b193)

**NOTE 2**: This works in the HERO5 Black, HERO4 Silver, HERO4 Black, for HERO4/5 Session you might want to read [HERO4-Session.md](https://github.com/KonradIT/goprowifihack/blob/master/HERO4/HERO4-Session.md) on how to wake it up and enter streaming mode. Since working with UDP protocols and system calls is hard, I recommend using GoProStream tool, which is a easy to use GoPro Streaming client written in Python: https://github.com/KonradIT/GoProStream

Works for HERO4, HERO+ and HERO5 and possibly future GoPro cameras.